# Need help with integrating $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin2x\cos x\,dx$ using $2\sin A\cos B$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometric-integrals

For context the question that I am currently stuck on is the second part of a question with 2 parts. I was able to solve the first part of the question, which is: Given $\sin(A + B)+\sin(A – B)=k\sin A\cos B$, find $k$. My answer for the first part of this question was $k=2$, which is correct. However, now I am struggling with the second part of the question despite multiple attempts at trying to solve it, which gave me incorrect answers.

The second part of the question which I am currently stuck on is as follows: Hence, find the exact value of $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin 2x\cos x\,dx$. I have tried to solve the question using what I could gather from the first part of the question, since the word "Hence" suggested that I had to use something from the first part. However, in the end, I got the incorrect answer for the question. Here is my current working for the second part of this question which I am stuck on:

$$\sin 2x\cos x\\
=\cos x(2\sin x\cos x)\\
=2\sin x\cos^2x\\
=2\sin x(1-\sin^2x)\\
=2\sin x-2\sin^3x\\
=2\sin x-2(\sin x)^3\\
\int{\sin2x\cos x\,dx}\\
=2\int{\sin x}\,dx-2\int(\sin x)^3\,dx\\
=2(-\cos x)-2\frac{(\sin x)^4}{-4\cos x}+c\\
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\sin2x\cos x\,dx}\\
=((2(-\cos\frac{\pi}{4}))-2(\frac{(\sin\frac{\pi}{4})^4}{-4\cos\frac{\pi}{4}}))-(2(-\cos0)-2(\frac{(\sin0)^4}{-4\cos0})\\
=-\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{3}+2\\
=-\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{3}}{8}\right)+2\\
=2-\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{8}\right)\\
=2-\sqrt{2}+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{16}\\
=\frac{32-14\sqrt{2}}{16}$$

As can be seen, the answer I got was: $\frac{32-14\sqrt{2}}{16}$. However, the correct answer is supposed to be $\frac{4-\sqrt{2}}{6}$.

May I know how to solve the second part of this question? I am still unsure as to where I went wrong and how I am actually supposed to solve this part of the question.

Comment: Try splitting $\sin^3(x)$ into $sin(x)(1-cos^2(x))$ as your result after is wrong.

Comment: You should get this integral $-2\int sin(x)(1-cos(x))dx$ which implies $-2\int sin(x) + 2\int sin(x)cos^2(x)dx$ then follow on with u substitution for the second and things should cancel. Then you can calculate with the bounds of the integral with change of variables and so forth ...

Comment: Set $A=2x,\,B=x$.

Answer (score 4):

When you simplify as $\sin 2x \cos x=2\sin x \cos^2 x$ in your second step from beginning, you can carry out integration right here by substitution
$$\cos x =t \Rightarrow -\sin x \, dx = dt$$

so your integral looks like
$$\int_1^{1/\sqrt{2}} -2t^2 \, dt$$

Comment: I think I get what you mean but I am still confused. Is it alright if you could show me another example of how this is done? Do you just assume a random algebraic variable as the value of $cosx$? But how does that help in simplifying the integration? I’m still quite confused.

Comment: @Arcane See [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-by-substitution.html) and [this](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Mount_Royal_University/MATH_1200%3A_Calculus_for_Scientists_I/4%3A_Integral_Calculus/4.1%3A_Integration_by_Substitution) for explanation and examples of this method.

Comment: This problem can easily be solved by using factor formula